# How to Zoom out/Zoom In within browser of Silverlight Spy?

Tags: silverlight

How can i Zoom out/In the webpage showed in browser within Silverlight Spy(http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy)?

I tried with `Ctrl -` / `Ctrl +` but nothing has changed with my application UI.

Answer (score 0):

Description of [XAML Spy](http://xamlspy.com/learn/whats-new-slspy) mentions zooming capabilities in "New features" section:

> Zoom & pan the UI of a running XAML application.

As it`s an extention of Silverlight Spy my guess is there`s no zooming in SL Spy. There`s none in UI too and standard controls like `Ctrl +` and `Ctrl-Mousewheel` does not work either so here you go.